# Excel drag-formula not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a "subscription" column in column A. A1 is "12000". I want C1 to be "A1/12" AND D1 to be "A1/12". However, if I make the formula for C1 "A1/12" and then drag to the right, D1 will try to become "B1/12" which I DO NOT WANT.

I do not just want to make A1 a constant, because I want that when I copy and paste this onto the following rows, C2 and D2 should be "A2/12" and NOT "A1/12".

Thoughts? Sorry for the obfuscated explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just lock the cell. This is done with dollar signs, or when you put the reference, press F4.

```
=$A$1/12
```

And you can drag it without the formula changing the `A1`.

If you want it to change with changing rows, just lock the column A:

```
=$A1/12
```

Comment: Yes but I don't want to do that because if I then copy and paste that whole row several times, the formula for these new rows will still refer to A1 and not A2, A3, A4, etc.

Comment: @user3175426 Your last line implied for me that you wanted A1/12 there as well. I edited my answer.

Comment: Ah. Sorry about that, I was trying to convey that I did not want "A1/12". Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: @user3175426 Okay, I edited the wording in your question a bit, to match that :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the dollar sign to fix the reference:

```
=$A$1/12
```

You might want to have a look at this for more information

http://www.notjustnumbers.co.uk/2011/05/excel-tip-dollar-sign-in-formula-fixing.html